# why did my if(isset($_POST) doesn't work?

Tags: php, sql, database, odbc

I want to insert values in the database by using form and submit button. It suppose to be that, after user click the submit button, the insert code will be run perfectly by updating the values that user have choose (value from dropdown and checkbox). But the `if(isset($_POST['btnSave']))` was display at `var_dump($_POST)` instead of inside if loops.

```
<?php
    $varUsrGrpID = isset($_REQUEST["dduser"])?$_REQUEST["dduser"]:"";
    $varAction = isset($_REQUEST["action"])?$_REQUEST["action"]:"";

    if ($varAction == "savedata")
    {
        if(isset($_POST['btnSave']))
        { 
            $checkBox = implode(',', $_POST['namaMenu']);

            if(strlen($checkBox)>=0)
            {

                foreach($_POST['namaMenu'] as $checkBox)
                {
                        $strConvert = "select CAST ('Y' as char) as eg";
                        $rsconvert = odbc_exec($dbconnVOT,$strConvert);

                        if (odbc_fetch_row($rsconvert))
                        {
                            $convertID = odbc_result($rsconvert, "eg");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            exit();
                        }


                        $strInsertData = "insert into tblMenuAkses
                            (usrgrpid, menuid, menuakses)
                             values
                            (".checknull($GLOBALS["varUsrGrpID"]).",'$checkBox',
                            $convertID)";


                        $rsInsert = odbc_exec($dbconnVOT,$strInsertData);

                        if(!$rsInsert)
                        {
                            writeErr($strInsertData,odbc_errormsg(),'skrinMenu.php',$ErrFilePath);
                            $msg = "error";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $msg = "Success";
                        }

                }
            }

        }
        else
        {
            var_dump($_POST);
        }

    }   

    ?>

    <script>

function sendData(varActionSed)
{

    if(document.getElementById("dduser").value=="")
    {
        alert("Please choose 'dduser'");
        document.getElementById("dduser").focus();
        return false;
    }


    document.getElementById("action").value=varActionSed;
    document.getElementById("frm1").submit();

}   

</script>
<form name="frm1" id="frm1" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="action" id="action" value="">
<table align= "center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
    <tr>&nbsp;</tr>
    <tr>
            <td width="170" height="20:px" valign="top"><b>User<font style="color:#ff0000">*</font></b></td>
            <td valign="top" align="center" width="15:px"><b>:</b></td>
            <td valign="top">

    <?php
    echo "<select name=\"dduser\" id=\"dduser\">";
    echo "<option value=\"\">Please choose</option>";
    $sqlGetUsrGrp = "SELECT * FROM tblUsrGrp";
    $rs = odbc_exec($dbconnVOT,$sqlGetUsrGrp);

    if ($rs)
    {
        while(odbc_fetch_row($rs))
        {
            echo "<option value=\"".odbc_result($rs,"UsrGrpID")."\" ".($varUsrGrpID==odbc_result($rs,"UsrGrpID")?"selected":"").">".odbc_result($rs,"UsrGrpNama")."</option>";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "error - ".odbc_errormsg();
    }
    echo "</select>";
    ?>


            </td>

    </tr>

        <?php

        $varMenuIDSumm="";
        $strMenuID="select * from tblMenuAkses";
        $rsMenuID=odbc_exec($dbconnVOT, $strMenuID);
        $countMenuID=0;
        while(odbc_fetch_row($rsMenuID))
        {
            $countMenuID++; 
            if($countMenuID==1)
            {
                $varMenuIDSumm=odbc_result($rsMenuID,"MenuID");
            }
            else
            {
                $varMenuIDSumm.=",".odbc_result($rsMenuID,"MenuID");
            }
        }   


        $menuID=array();
        $menuID=implode(",",$varMenuID);
        $strGetMenu="select * from tblMenu where MenuNama != 'sokong' and menunama not in ('Daftar Lejer Mengikut Dana')";

        $rs=odbc_exec($dbconnVOT, $strGetMenu);
        if($rs)
        {
            while (odbc_fetch_row($rs))
            {
                echo '<tr><td>';
                echo '<input type="checkbox" name="namaMenu[]" id="namaMenu" value='.odbc_result($rs,"menuID").'><b>&nbsp;'.odbc_result($rs,"MenuNama").'</b>' ;
                echo '</td></tr>';

            }

        }   

        ?>

<tr>
    <center>
        <input type="button" name="btnSave" id="btnSave" onClick="javascript:sendData('savedata');" value = "submit">
    </center>   
</tr>

</table>
</form>
```

Any help will be much appreciated . TQ

Comment: Could you add the `var_dump` result? Maybe it's `action` which is not set to `saveData` or something else.

Comment: @rap-2-h var dump result : `array(3) { ["action"]=> string(8) "savedata" ["ddKumpPenguna"]=> string(1) "4" ["namaMenu"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "4" } }` , that is the `var_dump` result. The result seems like there is nothing wrong with the code. I don't know what is wrong and why my code doesn't update the value in the database

Answer (score 0):

check you html code with name and value for submit eg

```
 <input type='submit' name = 'btnSave' value = 'btnSave' />
```

Comment: Thanks, but I already tried it . But it doesn't work either .